# relative path 2 level up in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery plug-in called [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) and I need to reference the image path as an argument like
`$.backstretch("../../img/xxx.jpg");`

Because the `img` folder is two level up from the index, I've referenced as `../../img/xxx.jpg` but it doesn't work.

With PHP, I can start from the root `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but this is PHP specific and I presume there might be something similar to this for Javascript.

I tried this article as well [CSS Trick](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)
but no luck.

Comment: if you start the path with the character '/', it means root.

Comment: Is index in your server's root folder? If yes, then items from upper levels won't be accessible from javascript.

Comment: I tried that one, too. But it's not pointing to the image in question.

Comment: @ghaxx my index is in two level down from the root. I am using Codeigniter and it's structured like that. Root -> application -> view -> index

Comment: @Seong Lee: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter in particular, but such frameworks tend to have some clever redirects and relative position of files in project may not be the same as on the rendered page. 

Maybe there's already a folder for images predefined somewhere in the app? For example `public/img` or `assets/img`...

Answer (score 4):

You should give the `full path` here like

```
$.backstretch("http://example.com/img/xxx.jpg");
```

In **Css** it works fine but here you should give the `full url path`

Read once again http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Thanks. interesting how it only allows url path.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `/img/xxx.jpg` - starting with a slash makes the path relative to your web root, exactly like `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: I am not having luck starting with `/`

Comment: I was mistaken with the root level that I regarded its child (the actual folder containing web project) as the root. With the correct use of `/` other ones work fine except this particular Backstretch plug-in that only seems to take full url.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in php is the same than starting the url with `/` in javascript.

Comment: I was mistaken with the root level that I regarded its child (the actual folder containing web project) as the root. With the correct use of `/` other ones work fine except this particular Backstretch plug-in that only seems to take full url.